# yield return multiple IEnumerables

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a test function that returns an `IEnumerable`, which inside, I want to `yield return` other functions that return `IEnumerable`.

```
public IEnumerable Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Foo!");
    yield break;
}

public IEnumerable Bar()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bar!");
    yield break;
}

public IEnumerable Foobar()
{
    foreach (var o in Foo())
    {
        yield return o;
    }

    foreach (var o in Bar())
    {
        yield return o;
    }
}
```

However, this "Foobar" function will have many more inner functions that return IEnumerable.

Is there any shorter way to do this instead of having to `foreach` and iterate over very function?

Comment: In this instance there is a shorter way. Could this be reopened?

Comment: Whatever you basically use `IEnumerable<object>` then build a `var enumerables = new List<IEnumerable<object>>() { Foo(), Bar(), ... }` and write `foreach (var o in enumerables.SelectMany(z => z)) { yield return o; }`